# How to execute commands in exucutable via python script

Tags: python, linux, audio, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

Currently i can send commands to the shell but as soon as i run the "bluetooth-player"  exucutable i cant send commands to the shell anymore [Here is a image of what it outputs into the command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz4fe.png) 
Here i have a example of my code i am using to run this simple script [Here is the example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3xjY.png)
If anyone one has a better way to do this or know how to send commands to the "bluetooth-player" please let me know

I am using a raspberry pi

Comment: you can use subprocess.call

Comment: Please post your code and errors directly in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use Subprocess() or Os.Popen(), these two will help you to get the shell output in a variable. You can make decision based on the output to run the next command.

check this out:
https://janakiev.com/blog/python-shell-commands/